# Looking for a biological/physiological mechanism ... effect of diet on those who exercise vs those who don't

Tags: exercise

I'm researching the effect of adherence to Mediterranean diet on levels of inflammation in the body (C-reactive protein & a couple of other markers).  I want to stratify participants over levels of exercise (which I believe is an effect modifier) and need to come up with a biological/physiological mechanism whereby the Mediterranean diet would have a different effect on CRP in people who exercise versus those who don't?
Would really appreciate any pointers here.

Comment: I don't quite follow. You say you are trying to investigate the levels of CRP when on a specific diet. Is the logical course of investigation not (do experiment + collect data on exercise habits --> see if exercise habits made a difference, and if so what kind of difference)? You're jumping the gun trying to come up with mechanisms differentiating an unestablished link. Perhaps baseline levels of CRP in those who exercise would also differ. In that case you should probably treat the cases separately, because it's not obvious what kind of normalisation to use to account for these effects.

Comment: I agree that would be the logical course of action BUT I have to use an existing data base - I am not collecting new data.  The supervisor says I have to suggest a biological mechanism to justify why I want to stratify according to exercise and I have to specify this  in my proposal up front...  But maybe that is sufficient to say that I expect baseline CRP to be lower in those who exercise

Comment: OK! I don't know much about the effects of exercise on CRP though- I'll try to look it up myself, but what is your reasoning behind thinking that baseline levels of CRP are lower in individuals who exercise? I know there is a lot of talk of exercise being helpful in health conditions characterised by high levels of inflammation, but exercise itself induces micro-tears in muscles, which should lead to elevation fo some inflammatory markers. This would probably be a short-lived effect after strenuous exercise, but again I dont't quite know the balanace of these effects and how CRP

Comment: specifically is effected. But at least that's more of a biologicial-mechanism explanation than hearsay about the benefits of exercise!